# Add a wishlist heart in a product image HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have this HTML & CSS code

```css
  .products .product{
        margin: 2em 0;
        width: 300px;
        height: 400px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

  .product img{
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="product">
 <img src="/img/place-holder.png">
  <div class="product-text">
   <h4><a href="/Product.html">Produkt</a></h4>
   <h4>199&nbsp;SEK</h4>
 </div>
```

I want to add a "add to wish list" heart button inside the image,but  it cannot be a part of the image, and when clicked the heart needs to turn to red

[Here is the design goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G94In.png)

Comment: Look into [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Also, your use of `<h4>` seems to be incorrect. Headings should be used to establish document structure and the heading level should indicate how sections nest within one another/establish the section hierarchy. You should not use headings because of the style the browser sets the text to. That's what CSS is for.

Comment: Is it better to use paragraphs you say?

Comment: Could use `<p>`, but that means new paragraph or new thought. If you just want something on its own line, use `<div>` and use CSs to style the element's text any way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i figured it out

i had yo use *Input* to make the heart change color to red on click

```css
.heart{
        color: #000;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-top: auto;
        z-index: 999;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .heart-checkbox{
        display: none;
    }


    .heart-checkbox:checked + .heart {
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="heart-checkbox" id="heart-checkbox">
<label for="heart-checkbox" class="heart">&#10084;</label>
```

that will give you the option to change the heart color on click

Answer (score 2):

```js
var clicked = false;

function myfunction() {
  clicked = !clicked;
  const el = document.getElementById("btn");
  if (clicked) {
    el.style.color = "red"
  } else {
    el.style.color = "black"
  }

}
```

```css
.products .product {
  margin: 2em 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.product img {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png?20190716190036">
  <p id="btn" onclick="myfunction()">
    &#10084;
  </p>
  <div class="product-text">
    <h4><a href="/Product.html">Produkt</a></h4>
    <h4>199&nbsp;SEK</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!
But i was hoping for somthing with just only html and css, i do not want to use js for that

Comment: @MalekMshinesh You tagged this question with JavaScript?

Comment: You are right, i forgot to edit that, but i even tried your code and for some reason the heart is not showing

Comment: @MalekMshinesh It's not my answer but it does work. The person who answered is using Wikimedia for the icon so perhaps it's blocked on your end? If you don't want to use JavaScript, you're going to have to look into using CSS only toggles: https://dev.to/dcodeyt/creating-a-css-only-toggle-switch-5cg3